# Infinite UIScrollView using Duplicate End Pages

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview

I am implementing an infinite UIScrollView using duplicate end pages.  Specifically, I have 3 ViewControllers whose views I add as subviews to the UIScrollView content.  So in effect, the UIScrollView content looks like below (V1 = Viewcontroller's View 1, V2, Viewcontroller's View 2, V3 = ViewController's View)

UIScrollView's Content:
[V3][V1][V2][V3][V1]

When the user scrolls rightwards from V2 to V3 to V1, I use "scrollRectToVisible" to shift the ScrollView to V1 in the 2nd position, making it seem endless.  Likewise, when the user scrolls leftwards from V2 to V1 to V3, I shift the scrollview to V3 at the 2nd to last position.

Codewise, this looks like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender {    

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {         
        // user is scrolling to leftwards and has reached the position 0 of the scrollview         
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(960,0,scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];     
    }    
    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == 1280) {         
        // user is scrolling rightward and has reached the last position of the scrollview        
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320,0,scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];  
        }
    }
 }
```

The problem I have here is that the ViewControllers have UITableViews in them.  For example, V1 has a UITableView.  If the user has gone to row 10 of the V1's UITableView, I believe I would need to synchronize the state of the UITableView among the V1 views in the scrollview.

The user only sees the rightmost [V1] for a split second or when they only drag the scrollview halfway, but they could still notice that it's not the same TableView if the state isnt synchronized.

Is there some way around this?  One way I thought is to just to save the state and then update all the V1 so that they are showing the same thing.

Is it possible to have two UITableView objects that automatically mirror each other somehow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that:

> If the user has gone to row 10 of the V1's UITableView, I believe I would need to synchronize the state of the UITableView among the V1 views in the scrollview.

which means you have several instances of the same V1 ViewController.

> Is it possible to have two UITableView objects that automatically mirror each other somehow?

Yes, using a NSNotificationCenter on the NSUserDefaults should do the trick but maybe you can do something more efficient.

Instead of using

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender
```

you could give a try to

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

to re-arrange only 3 VC (one instance for each class) on a certain condition (which is usually moving the VC which has completely disappear from the screen). So you will save 2 VC and won't have to deal with synchronizing instances of the same class.

Apple released a great video about infinite scroll view (WWDC 2011, Session 104 - Advanced Scroll View Techniques).

Hope this helps. Good luck.